# How to create custom expectations for Camel MockEndpoints

Tags: mocking, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that receives different types of messages and I only have control over some of the messages. I want to check that certain messages are received at least once and ignore any other types of messages that flow through the route. It means that I don't know how many messages the mock endpoint needs to receive before we can assert it.

The code below demonstrates the problem. the testExactBodies() test works just fine, but I have no idea how I can make the testLenientBodies() work.

This is a simplified example and in the real world, the message bodies are complex XML and the assertions I need to make on them are more complex.

```
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExpectationTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    private static final String MOCK_ENDPOINT = "mock:expectation_mock";
    private static final String START_URI = "direct:expectation_test";

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(START_URI).routeId("expectation_test")
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "$simple{body}")
                        .to(MOCK_ENDPOINT);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testExactBodies() throws InterruptedException {
        // Get the mock endpoint
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint(MOCK_ENDPOINT);
        // Set the expectations that we want to check.
        // Here we expect exactly these 3 bodies
        // This will implicitly call mockEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(3)
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("x", "y", "z");
        // Sets the timeout to wait for the expectations to be satisfied
        mockEndpoint.setResultWaitTime(10000);

        // Send the testdata to the route
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "x");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "y");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "z");

        // Assert that the expectations are satisfied. Will wait until expectations are satisfied or a timeout occurs
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLenientBodies() throws InterruptedException {
        // Get the mock endpoint
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint(MOCK_ENDPOINT);
        // Set the expectations that we want to check.

        // We want to check that the bodies "x", "y" and "z" arrive at least once and in any order and ignore any other bodies, but how?
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder("x", "y", "z");
        // mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrderAndIgnoreOtherBodies("x", "y", "z");

        // Sets the timeout to wait for the expectations to be satisfied
        mockEndpoint.setResultWaitTime(10000);

        // Send the testdata to the route
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "a");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "y");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "z");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "b");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "y");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "r");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "c");
        template.sendBody(START_URI, "x");

        // Assert that the expectations are satisfied. Will wait until expectations are satisfied or a timeout occurs
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

EDIT ==============================

A workaround would be this:

```
@Test
public void testLenientBodiesBruteForce() throws InterruptedException {
    // Get the mock endpoint
    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint(MOCK_ENDPOINT);

    // Send the testdata to the route
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "a");
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "y");
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "z"); // Comment out this line to make the test fail
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "b");
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "y");
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "r");
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "c");
    template.sendBody(START_URI, "x");

    // We want to check that the bodies "x", "y" and "z" arrive at least once and in any order and ignore any other bodies
    boolean satisfied = false;
    int timeout = 10;
    int i = 0;
    while (!satisfied && i < timeout) {
        Set<String> expectedBodies = new HashSet<>();
        expectedBodies.add("x");
        expectedBodies.add("y");
        expectedBodies.add("z");
        for (Exchange exchange : mockEndpoint.getExchanges()) {
            expectedBodies.remove(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        }
        System.out.println("ExpectedBodies not yet seen: " + expectedBodies);
        satisfied = expectedBodies.isEmpty();
        if (!satisfied) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }

    assertTrue(satisfied);
}
```

Comment: If you have a copy of the Camel in Action book such use-case is covered there in the testing chapter.

Comment: I take it you mean the use-case using mock.expects(). That still sets the number of expected messages though, how can I make Runnable tell the mock that all expectations are satisfied, so assertIsSatisfied() will return?

Comment: Is the Runnable run each time a new exchange is received on the mockendpoint?

Comment: It seems that what I actually want to do is add my own custom CountDownLatch to the endpoint, so the waitForCompleteLatch can wait for my custom expectations to be satisfied.